# How can create a batch script using variables. This makes the file but it wont move the file and delete the source file

Tags: batch-file

[Picture of the issuee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwMWX.png)

```
@echo off

set date="%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%"

if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\python_scripts\TEST\logs\grab_ip\%date%" mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\python_scripts\TEST\logs\grab_ip\%date%"

set source="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\python_scripts\TEST\logs\grab_ip"
set target="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\python_scripts\TEST\logs\grab_ip\%date%"

Echo Source is %source%
Echo Target is %target%

Pause
Robocopy.exe %source% %target%
Pause
```

Comment: 1. Please no pictures of code or error messages, copy the text here! 2. [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code properly! 3. Describe exactly what you want and what actually happens; consult [mcve] for that! also take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Please change the new variable name from `date`, that is already the name of an important system variable. Perhaps `Set "_Date=%DATE:~-10%"`, then `Set "_Date=%_Date:/=-%"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `3` line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which may, *(if my assumptions are correct)*, do what you want:

```bat
@Set "source=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\python_scripts\TEST\logs\grab_ip"
@Set "_date=%DATE:~-10%"
@"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" "%source%" "%source%\%_date:/=-%" /E /Move /XD "%_date:/=-%">NUL
```

The above is an entire script, do not add or remove any other line or command, before testing. The script assumes your `%DATE%` value separators are forward slashes, if they are not please modify as necessary.